# "a" pode significar "em vez de"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões, frases

**a** pode ter um significado como **em vez de**?

> Carregá-lo pelo resto da vida **a** dividi-lo com você!

Comment: Oi Majid, tomei a liberdade de editar tua postagem, se não concordar com algo, por favor reverta.

Comment: @stafusa Tudo bom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece haver um "prefiro" implícito nessa frase:

> [Prefiro] carregá-lo pelo resto da vida a dividi-lo com você!

E o verbo "preferir" rege-se (vide, e.g., [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/preferir-mais-uma-vez/6586)) com a preposição "a": preferir A a B, em que, de fato, esse "a" tem o significado de "ao invés de".

Comment: Discordo e concordo. Acho possibilíssimo estares certo, mas também há “a tropa atacará o portão aos aldeões” ou “a tropa atacará o portão ao os aldeões”. Não sei se tal uso é culto, porém. Digo, ele até parece correto, mas parecer não é ser.

Comment: Pode ser um uso da preposição “a” vindo de “preferir”, uma confusão de sentidos, achando que esse “a” não fizesse parte do verbo.

Comment: @Schilive, sério que essa frase que você coloca está correta? Poderia explicar como? Se preferir eu posso postar como pergunta no site.

Comment: Stafusa, isso é exatamente o que eu não sei. Soa-me correta, mas me parece engano meu ao mesmo tempo. A frase “atacaram o castelo aos aldeões” deve ter um “preferir” omitido, i.e., esse “atacaram” talvez seja “ataca[r] [preferi]ram”? Soa-me correto, mas honestamente acho que é uma armadilha. Será que o escritor da frase do Majid caiu na armadilha? Falo “armadilha”, pois nem o Houaiss nem o Aulete dão tal significado.

Comment: Sim, acho que se pode atacar o portão aos aldeões: "E depois de ameaçarem que se não entregassem o fugitivo podia haver tiroteio, sabes o que fizeram os tropas? Atacaram o portão aos aldeões!" Mas esse `ao` (a+a) não é equivalente a um `a`, é equivalente a um `à` (a+a). Esta diferença é óbvia em pt-PT, porque o "a" soa fechado (ã) e o à soa aberto (á); em pt-BR não se ouve diferença, e isso causa complicações.

Comment: Essas frases me parecem muito estranhas - se vocês quiserem elaborar um pouco sobre como elas são adequadas, por favor, chequem a pergunta que acabo de postar: [É correto e o que significa “Atacar o portão aos aldeões.”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/8456/2764). @ANevesthinksSEisevil Schilive

Comment: Sim, concordo.  Uma pessoa prefere alguma coisa **a** outra, embora popularmente muita gente diga (erroneamente) "eu prefiro ir ao cinema **do que** ficar em casa"

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo da frase essa colocação fica errada, por isso é preferível não utilizar o "a" com essa finalidade, é melhor usar "ao invés de"