# É correto e o que significa "Atacar o portão aos aldeões."?

Tags: significado, preposições, frases

Há falantes nativos que consideram gramaticalmente correto o seguinte:

> E depois de ameaçarem que se não entregassem o fugitivo podia haver tiroteio, sabes o que fizeram os tropas? **Atacaram o portão aos aldeões**!

e até mesmo

> a tropa atacará o portão ao os aldeões

São mesmo corretas essas frases?

Eu sequer tenho certeza de entender seu significado - seria o mesmo que "Atacaram o portão *ao invés dos* aldeões."?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119742/discussion-on-question-by-stafusa-e-correto-e-o-que-significa-atacar-o-portao-a).

Answer (score 4):

O segundo exemplo é agramatical.

> a tropa atacará o portão **ao os** aldeões

"ao" é a contracção da preposição a e do artigo ou pronome o.
"ao os" seria a+o+os:

- a - preposição
- o - artigo definido masculino singular
- os - artigo definido masculino plural

Não conheço nem imagino uma situação em que a gramática permita dois artigos seguidos.

---

Mas o primeiro exemplo eu acho que sim, que é correto, porque não?

> - Atacaram os portões aos aldeões.
> - Atacaram-lhes os portões.

Alguém atacou os portões (objeto direto), dos/aos aldeões (objeto indireto).

Alguém, um inimigo qualquer, atacou: não aos monjes, não aos mercadores, mas aos aldeões.
E atacou-lhes: não as suas janelas, não os seus telhados, mas os seus portões.

Eu entendo ainda, nesta construção, algum ênfase não nos inimigos atacarem algo dos aldeões, mas em algo dos aldeões ser atacado.

---

Não sei explicar o porquê, gramaticalmente. Sei que me soa bem, e que consigo construir uma frase assim.

É possível que seja uma construção exclusiva a Portugal, e que não faça sentido no Brasil.
Talvez seja um hispanicismo, como é sugerido por Wtrmute [num comentário desta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8456/%c3%89-correto-e-o-que-significa-atacar-o-port%c3%a3o-aos-alde%c3%b5es#comment19225_8456). A influência do galego é clara no norte de Portugal; também a do leonês/mirandês, e a do castelhano.

---

Por exemplo, eu poderia escrever:

> Irritados com a resistência, os salteadores normandos berraram que *agora é que ia ser*, que se os aldeões não se rendessem toda a gente ia ser exterminada... lançaram ameaças, insultos e flechas sobre os muros da fortificação, mas mesmo assim os aldeões resistiram e não se renderam.
> Então, com crueldade premeditada, os normandos procuraram quebrar os aldeões sem se arriscarem. Incendiaram-lhes as casas que estavam fora da fortificação. Destruiram-lhes os campos. Cortaram-lhes as oliveiras e as árvores de fruto. Chacinaram-lhes os animais. Lançaram-lhes flechas incendiárias sobre a fortificação. E, finalmente, com uivos loucos e ferozes, **atacaram-lhes o portão** da fortificação.

Haverá maneiras diferentes de escrever isto, claro. Não há sempre?
Mas parece-me uma construção perfeitamente legítima.

E se se pode construir com pronome (-lhes), eu entendo que se pode construir com o substantivo original - mesmo se por vezes uma forma seja preferida e usual, e a outra possa soar dissonante.
Estarei enganado?

Por exemplo, podia escrever:

> Então, com crueldade premeditada, os normandos procuraram quebrar os aldeões sem se arriscarem. Incendiaram aos aldeãos as casas que estavam fora da fortificação, ignorando claramente o merdado. Destruiram os campos dos aldeões, mas sem tocarem nos que rodeavam o mosteiro. Destruiram aos aldeões o seu futuro e o seu sustento: cortaram as oliveiras e as árvores de fruto, chacinaram os animais de carga e de criação, pisaram os campos as culturas. Em fúria, lançaram sobre os aldeões e a sua fortificação uma chuva de flechas incendiárias. E, com uivos loucos e ferozes, **atacaram por fim aos aldeões o portão da fortificação**. Em breve a sua fortificação cairia, e no lugar da fortificação ficariam apenas cinzas e ossadas - como mensagem e testemunho.

Comment: Obrigado! As construções com o "lhe" me parecem naturais o bastante e o passo para o pronome a que se refere também.

Comment: ANeves, esses textos são citações? Devias indicar a fonte. Se não são, devias dizer que são exemplos (porque citação tem mais peso, n'é?). São perfeitamente corriqueiras coisas como: *roubaram o portão aos aldeões* ou  *destruíram /  queimaram / consertaram / pintaram o portão aos aldeões*. Mas *atacaram o portão aos aldeões* soa-me estranho, mesmo sendo a mesma construção. Possivelmente é só por ser incomum. Agora, é possível que isto soe ainda mais estranho aos brasileiros: encontra-se facilmente "roubaram o telemóvel ao" (João, meu filho), mas nenhum "roubaram o celular ao" (fala @stafusa).

Comment: Sim, @Jacinto, não creio que se ouça, em pt-BR, "roubaram o celular _ao_ João", seria sempre "roubaram o celular _do_ João" ou "roubaram o celular _dele_". Já "roubaram-lhe o celular" soa mais natural, embora provavelmente não coloquial. Essa parece ser mesmo uma diferença transatlântica.

Comment: ANeves, se preferir posso colocar como outra pergunta, mas me restou a dúvida: em "atacaram o portão aos aldeões", o verbo está aceitando um objeto indireto, ou dois objetos diretos em que um deles parece/é "direto com preposição"? Penso que essa impressão é a causa do estranhamento com a construção, já que "atacar" é transitivo direto. De outra forma: qual é o papel sintático de "aos aldeões"?

Comment: @Jacinto, ah, sim tens razão; esclareci que o texto foi construído por mim.

Comment: @stafusa , acho que essa dúvida cabe perfeitamente na parte da pergunta "e o que significa". :) Vou editar: eu vejo um objeto direto,os portões, e um indireto, [a]os aldeões. Se calhar o verbo _atacar_ é só transitivo direto, e daí a estranheza desta forma... hmm, boa dúvida.

Comment: Bom, o Jacinto parece inclinado para isso, e eu sinto também alguma estranheza quando tento jogar com o verbo.

Comment: Eu tinha posto vários comentários acima. Se aqueles foram "moved to chat", porquê esses não? Tenho a impressão de estar sendo vigiada.....

Comment: @Lambie, movem-se para o chat discussões -- conversas também, mas depende --, pois não deve haver discussão nos comentários. Ao meu ver, não houve discussão nesta seção de comentários, apenas perguntas e respostas, o que eu acho que é permitido, até onde eu sei.

Comment: @Schilive Como se diz em francês: On ne prête qu'aux riches. Só vejo mesmo uma discussão. Por favor, para de contradizer cada coisinha que digo.

Comment: Por acaso até havia um zelador que rondava, algo infrequentemente... mas reformou-se.  @Lambie , se achas que um ou mais comentários não cabem, "flaga-os" sem remorso que um moderador lhes há-de prestar atenção! As regras são para todos, e são iguais para todos. :)

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil É sutil, não óbvio. E que acontece sobre várias postagens. Por isso, não se pode sinalizar. O problema que tenho é com um moderador....

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil Tudo que eu disse acima foi "moved to chat" e agora o chat foi deletado. Entende? Para  mim: se diz: **atacaram AOS aldeões no portão** [por dizer atacar a alguém] ou  **atacaram o portão dos aldeões**. Eu francamente não entendo por que essa frase parece ser tão opaca para vocês,  nativo lusófonos....você ve outra leitura possível??

Comment: Nessa sua leitura: atacaram por fim aos aldeões o portão da fortificação, me parece uma estrutura do espanhol ou até francêsa, versão literária ou muito formal......porque normalmente em português sería: **por fim os aldeões atacaram o portão da fortificação**. A inversão que você propõe só tenho visto em português em **poesia**...:)